# Meaning when using should

Tags: meaning

There a sentence:
               'I was surprised that he should say such a thing.'

I don't quite understand it's meaning. I have 2 possible explanations, could       you tell me which one is right:

> 1)I was surprised that he HAD SAID say such a thing.
>
> 2)I was surprised that he COULD say such a thing.

Comment: By *could*, do you mean "*was able to"* or *"had decided to"*? Because *"I was surprised that he should speak French"* definitely does ***not*** mean *"I was surprised that he could speak French"*.

Comment: By 'could' I mean 'had decided'.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

In this context, should = would (makes a statement less blunt or direct)

'Should' is often used in contexts such as the one above, in which the speaker is "surprised" (actually means "shocked", in an implicit manner).